# Unity Addressable how to collect bundles to the server from any machine?

Tags: addressables

I'm using the Addressable directory system and was hoping it would help update bundles from any machine, but it doesn't. I really need help

I read a bunch of forums and also tried GPT(3,4) and still couldn’t find an answer :(